# Ubuntu copy dialogue stops at the last moment for a long time

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Whenever I try and copy a file to an USB flash disk, the progress bar runs till the end very fast and stops for an indeterminable time before it is complete.

Is there an issue with ubuntu or my flash disk is what I am not able to figure out. All I want is a realistic copy dialogue

Comment: Do you use USB 3.0 port to plugin your USB Drive?

Comment: Yeah, but the device is 2.0 I suppose

Comment: Same happens to me also, when I plugin USB 2.0 to USB 3.0 Port, in Ubuntu as well as Windows. I don't know exactly why does it happen. But using USB 2.0 in USB 2.0 port and USB 3.0 in USB 3.0 port work fine. You can use `lsusb` command to know about your ports version.

Answer (score 8):

This is because many filesystems buffer and then when they `flush` they have to wait for the device to do the actual writing.... Which takes a while.

I don't know that there's a good solution so that you see the actual write speed and progress.