# Copy to USB drive stops at ~99%

Tags: usb, nautilus, copy

Trying to copy file to USB drive (64GB, NTFS). File size was 242.7MB copy stopped at 242.2MB first time I tried and 242.5MB second time.

Waited more then 5 minutes and the operation should have easily finished by then.

I ended up using the command line to copy the file but this is terrible. Why does the copy operation stop? No other applications were open at the time.

I don't see the same issues when copying to network locations. I copied the same file across the WiFi to my server (Ubuntu 16.04) took approx 4s. Copied a 4.4GB file from the server to my laptop took approx 1min.

Laptop: Ubuntu 17.04. System 76 Oryx Pro, i7-7700HQ, 16GB RAM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu copy dialogue stops at the last moment for a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340353/ubuntu-copy-dialogue-stops-at-the-last-moment-for-a-long-time)